# Car shuddering, losing power

Tags: vauxhall, power-loss, motor-mounts, commodore

I have a VX Commodore 2000. A few times over the last few days it started to shudder as I reversed into a park and was about to conk out as I switched it off, then later as I drove home it started to shudder as I was driving, then losing power as I pressed on accelerator, and felt engine seemed to miss. Now I do know the engine mounts have gone in this car; could it be the steering rack? I have never driven a car with these issues before. Too scared to drive it and don't have a man to look at it or advise me on it.

Comment: You wrote _reversed into a park_    Do you mean it's an automatic transmission and you put it into "Park", or maybe it's a manual and you were reversing into a parking spot or ?  Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: it's an auto as I was reversing it started to shudder